# How to set the spell check in TexMaker to other languages in Ubuntu

Tags: texmaker, languages, dictionaries, persian

Is there any way to change the spell check language in TexMaker to Persian or any other language such as Spannish, Russian, and etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this question as I have already found the answer to it.

I am not sure how it works in Windows or MacOS; but I have tried the following steps and it worked on Ubuntu 22.04.

First of all, as I understand it, you need to download and install the corresponding dictionary to your language on your system; using the `.dic` file alone does not work:

```
Texmaker Error : Can’t open the dictionary
```

We can use `myspell` to install the dictionary. Writing `sudo apt install myspell-` and pressing the  <kbd>tab</kbd> button a several times leaves you with the available dictionaries:

```
myspell-bg          myspell-gd          myspell-pt-pt
myspell-cs          myspell-gv          myspell-ru
myspell-da          myspell-he          myspell-sk
myspell-de-de-1901  myspell-hr          myspell-sq
myspell-el-gr       myspell-hu          myspell-ss
myspell-en-au       myspell-hy          myspell-st
myspell-eo          myspell-lv          myspell-tl
myspell-es          myspell-nb          myspell-tn
myspell-et          myspell-nn          myspell-ts
myspell-fa          myspell-nr          myspell-uk
myspell-fo          myspell-ns          myspell-ve
myspell-fr          myspell-pl          myspell-xh
myspell-fr-gut      myspell-pt          myspell-zu
myspell-ga          myspell-pt-br
```

You can choose any one you want, in this case I will be installing the Farsi dicitionary by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt install myspell-fa
```

The dictionary files should be available at `/usr/share/hunspell/`  and `/usr/share/myspell/`. (If it is not, use the command `locate *.aff` to locate the directory which the dictionary files are placed in.)

Then go to the `options` in TexMaker, placed on the top bar, then choose `Configure Texmyaker`.
[image: Texmaker Screenshot]

Click the browse button to choose the spelling dictionary.